# Why does command substitution work in example 2 but not example 1?

Tags: linux, bash

EXAMPLE 1: from BASH terminal (doesn't work):

```
$(date | sed -r 's/[ ]{2,}/ /gi')
```

EXAMPLE 2: from a BASH shell script (does work):

```
ECHO_DATE=$(date | sed -r 's/[ ]{2,}/ /gi')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you're running the result of the evaluation in the `$()`. Right now, that result starts with `Mon`, so you'll get a `command not found` error. In the second, you're assigning the result to a variable. To see it immediately, you can do:

```bash
echo "$(date | sed -r 's/[ ]{2,}/ /gi')"
```

But you also don't need to evaluate an extra step at all:

```bash
date | sed -r 's/[ ]{2,}/ /gi'
```

I would also recommend checking out `man date`, because `date` has builtin formatting options.

Comment: yes running that in a subshell is kind of silly, and piping `date` to `sed` is extremely fragile. It works only in some locale and will break immediately when the locale changes. For example try `LC_ALL=ru_RU.utf8 date | sed -r 's/[ ]{2,}/ /gi'` or `LC_ALL=de_DE.utf8 date | ...` or `LC_ALL=el_GR.utf8 date | ...`. Always use the built-in formatting function of `date` instead of parsing the string and change it

Comment: Yep absolutely agreed @phuclv!

Comment: Two issues -- #1.) this was an example for demo purposes (e.g., date), #2.) I was unfamiliar w/the meaning of $(); thank you to those of you who helped me.